# Dart Analysis Detects and Unused Field...what am I missing?

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see from my code sample, I'm using this variable.  I also reference multiple times later in the class.

> Flutter Warning - info: The value of the field '_loadTimer' isn't used. (unused_field at [app] lib/models/knowledge_level/pb_cycle_permissions_collection.dart:12)

ng is: info: The value of the field '_loadTimer' isn't used. (unused_field at [app] lib/models/knowledge_level/pb_cycle_permissions_collection.dart:12)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:app/data/graphql/queries.dart';
import 'package:app/helpers/shared_logger.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import '../command_permission.dart';

class PBCyclePermissionsCollection
    with ListMixin<CommandPermission>, ChangeNotifier {
  Timer? _loadTimer;

  ///
  ///  CONSTRUCTION AND INITIALIZATION
  ///
  static final PBCyclePermissionsCollection _instance =
      PBCyclePermissionsCollection._internal();

  factory PBCyclePermissionsCollection() {
    return _instance;
  }

  /// ACCESS SINGLETON VIA  myPBCyclePermInstance = PBCyclePermissionsCollection()
  PBCyclePermissionsCollection._internal() {
    _loadTimer = Timer(_waitFirstLoad, _attemptLoad);
  }

  ///
  /// PRIVATE VARIABLES AND METHODS
  ///

  static final Duration _waitFirstLoad = Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  static final Duration _waitRetryLoad = Duration(seconds: 2);
  static final int _maxAttempts = 4;

  int _loadAttempts = 0;
  bool _isReady = false;
  bool _hasFailed = false;

  /// Storage of CommandPermissions List once loaded
  final List<CommandPermission> _list = [];

  void _attemptLoad() async {
    _loadAttempts++;
    SharedLogger.I().d('_attemptLoad() current load attempt: ${_loadAttempts}');

    try {
      final results = await Queries.getCommandPermissions();

      var data = results.data!['commandPermissions'];

      var permissions = <CommandPermission>[];
      for (var item in data) {
        permissions.add(CommandPermission.fromJson(item));
      }

      /// Populated class with loaded objects.
      _list.clear();
      _list.addAll(permissions);
      _isReady = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      SharedLogger.I().e('Error loading PBCycle Permissions - ${e}');
      _newAttempt();
    }
  }

  void _newAttempt() {
    SharedLogger.I().d(
        '_newTry() _loadAttempts: ${_loadAttempts} _maxAttempts:${_maxAttempts} '
        'creating new loadTimer for another try? : ${!(_loadAttempts >= _maxAttempts)}');
    if (_loadAttempts >= _maxAttempts) {
      _hasFailed = true;
      notifyListeners();
      // TODO: do we invalidate any existing data that may have been loaded before? Like if this load cycle is a refresh?
      // If so, we should reset _isReady and _list;
      return;
    }
    _loadTimer = Timer(_waitRetryLoad, _attemptLoad);
  }

  ///
  /// PUBLIC METHODS
  ///
  bool get isLoaded {
    return _isReady;
  }

  bool get hasFailed {
    return _hasFailed;
  }

  @override
  set length(int newLength) {
    throw ('length cannot be changed externally');
  }

  @override
  int get length {
    return _list.length;
  }

  @override
  CommandPermission operator [](int index) {
    return _list[index];
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, CommandPermission value) {
    throw ('Cannot modify list from outside');
  }
}
```

[Image of IDE with Code Sample and associated Dart Analysis Hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie3cb.png)

Comment: Is the error message consistent if you run `dart analyzer` manually or if you exit and restart your IDE?  BTW, unrelated, but `_loadTimer` probably could be declared as `late Timer` instead of being nullable.

Comment: I see both "package:app" and relative imports.  Choose one or the other.  If you use both, things get confused.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually using it, you're just setting the value multiple times

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Andrew is correct, but a bit unclear since unsure what 'it' refers to. Here's another way to explain what the warning message means:

Notice that the message says you are not using the *value*. You are using the variable, but not its value. You are assigning the value. To read the value would be using it.

That said, the question is answered, but I think the question is somewhat vague by asking "what am i missing". What do you (OP) want to achieve? I assume it's to not see that warning anymore. And that is what brings me to this post. I have similar issue. I too have a class variable for a Timer and I get this same warning message. One does not need to read the value in order to *use* a timer but the analyzer doesn't know that. While writing this response I have discovered that you can a suppress warning. How about this:

```
  // ignore: unused_field
  Timer? _loadTimer;
```